# Querying Storage Class with AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm implementing a file manager on top of S3 and I'm currently trying to implement seamless glacier archiving via LifeCycles. The S3 side of things with the LifeCycles is pretty straight forward. However I can't find a method which will return the actual Storage Class of the key. It's obviously available since the S3 control panel shows it.

In the documentation for Storage Classes they mention this Metadata object should be present ([S3 Using Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#storage-class-intro)):

> x-amz-storage-class   Storage class used for storing the object.

headObject documentation mentions that it should return Metadata but when I run it, no Metadata block is returned.

```
Delete-Marker: "",
Accept-Ranges: "bytes",
Expiration: "",
Restore: "",
Last-Modified: "Mon, 08 Sep 2014 20:27:39 GMT",
Content-Length: "3976807",
ETag: "0359f81b950a395d3f4ee0bf****",
Missing-Meta: "",
Version-Id: "Mb96ZF0dm506eXP***",
Cache-Control: "",
Content-Disposition: "",
Content-Encoding: "",
Content-Language: "",
Content-Type: "video/x-ms-wmv",
Expires: "",
Website-Redirect-Location: "",
Server-Side-Encryption: "",
SSECustomerAlgorithm: "",
SSECustomerKeyMD5: "",
Request-Id: "43AD99D48F****E"
```

Meanwhile the documentation claims that Metadata should be one of the fields returned:

```
Metadata => (associative-array<string>)
Associative array of <string> keys mapping to (string) values. Each array key should be    changed to an appropriate <string>.

A map of metadata to store with the object in S3.
<string> => (string)
The metadata value.
```

FYI, I'm using this documentation 
[AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html)

Any advice is appreciated as currently the only solution I found is either to run a getObject (which is not feasible since it'll download the whole object) or running a restoreObject on every call and checking its exception code. But that means that it's impossible to check a key's status without restoring it (if it's archived)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it. When I ran the following code:

```
$s3 = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory($config);
$result = $s3->listObjects(array(
    'Bucket' => 'somebucket'
));
echo $result;
```

I got this output and it contains StorageClass:

```
[Name] => soembucket
[Prefix] => Array
    (
    )

[Marker] => Array
    (
    )

[MaxKeys] => 1000
[IsTruncated] =>
[Contents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Key] => e2014090520140911a.jpg
                [LastModified] => 2014-09-04T21:06:49.000Z
                [ETag] => "7ae0adc21a443ab8d4499cabaa54157b"
                [Size] => 101961
                [Owner] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 8c1a9525cee6d6caa294e524b4bb1d28481e53473cc48a26e714e89665cb7afc
                        [DisplayName] => amazon_aws
                    )

                [StorageClass] => STANDARD
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Key] => e2014091220141002a.jpg
                [LastModified] => 2014-09-11T21:19:33.000Z
                [ETag] => "96882d755e7864bd01d75cb24673fb00"
                [Size] => 219311
                [Owner] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 8c1a9525cee6d6caa294e524b4bb1d28481e53473cc48a26e714e89665cb7afc
                        [DisplayName] => amazon_aws
                    )

                [StorageClass] => STANDARD
            )

    )

[EncodingType] =>
[RequestId] => 30BB77F212066343
```

Comment: I guess I could just listBucket with my key and get the StorageClass from there. Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: Excellent, that does work. Seems a little weird that head doesn't get this info but I can live with this :)